# Stable flag for a self adjoint operator in a symplectic vector space

Tags: symplectic-linear-algebra

I'm trying to learn some facts concerning symplectic spaces and I have found this affirmation I cannot prove:

If $x$ is self adjoint in a symplectic vector space then there's an isotropic flag $V_1\subset V_2\subset \cdots\subset V_n$ stable by $x$.

Here $2n$ is the dimension of the vector space.

I hope someone can give me a hint.
Thank you very much.